# Pie Chart MVC Razor Error "OutputStream is not Available when a custom TextWriter is used."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Recieving `OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.` error when attempting to call the write function on my chart.

Partial:

```
@{
var pieChart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 350, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
            .AddTitle("Reject Message Report")
            .AddSeries(
                name: "Rejects",
                chartType: "Pie",
                xValue: new[] { "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" },
                yValues: new[] { "2", "3", "4" });
}

@pieChart.Write();
```

Partent:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Action("RejectMessageReport", "ALS")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult RejectMessageReport(int business = 1, int cra = 0)
{
        RejectMessageReportViewModel model = new RejectMessageReportViewModel();
        return PartialView("_RejectMessageReport", model);
}
```

Comment: are you just trying to display the chart?

Comment: Where are you using this code ? When are you getting the error ?

Comment: Simply attempting to display this chart. I am rendering it on a partial view. Of course I want to load actual data into it, but for now I'm working at that simplest level.

Comment: How are you calling the partial view in your main view ?

Comment: Edited question above.

Comment: You should leave the View to only display the output.. not display and calculate (separation of concern).. so create the graph in a controller, then call that action in the View with `@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")`

Comment: The view will only display the graph. There is no calculation done in my view. If you're speaking of my hard coded arrays. They will be replaced with the ViewModels properties. This was merely my first attempt at rendering a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Chart.Write` method writes the output stream. Your current code is calling the action method inside the view of your parent action method. Razor is trying to execute the code for your main view and your child action methods view code ends it be returning the output.

You should use an image element and set the source of that as the url to the action method which renders the graph

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <img src="@Url.Action("RejectMessageReport", "ALS")" />
</div>
```

This way, when razor executes the code for your main view, it generates the markup for the image tag with src set as the url to the `RejectMessageReport` action method(`@Url.Action` method returns this url). Your browser will make a seperate call to load the image source for the img tag. No need to worry whether the output stream is available or not (for that call) after the image is written.

Comment: Is there a difference between using `@Url.Action` and `@Html.Action`?

Comment: `Url.Action` returns the url to the action method where Html.Action will be executed immediately.